# Connected, reduced, finite $k$-algebra is a domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I came across a proof of the statement that if $A$ is a finite, reduced, and connected $k$-algebra, then $A$ is a field extension of $k$. In the proof, we construct an inverse of a non-zero $a\in A$ by showing there must exist $n\geq 0, b\in A$ such that $$a^n(ab-1)=0$$ and hence hence $ab=1$. It seems to me that this only follows if $A$ is a domain, but it is not obvious to me why this is the case. How does it follow from being reduced, connected, and finite that $A$ has no zero divisors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it isn't clear that $a^n$ is a regular element (which is what would minimally work).

Do you know basic Wedderburn-Artin theory?

Finite + reduced implies it is a finite product of field extensions of $k$, and the connectedness requirement whittles that down to a single field extension of $k$.

Another way to do it is to note that since it's finite, it is a finite product of local rings. By connectedness, it's a single local ring. The radical of a finite local ring is nilpotent, so if it is also reduced, the radical is zero, and hence you are just looking at a field.

Comment: It's actually the proof that finite+reduced implies it is a finite product of field extensions where this argument came up. They reduce the implication to that of the connected case, which is why I was so specific. I like the local ring argument!